# Redshift: Table is deleted from the DB with in 5 minutes automatically

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create the table in the redshift DB using the SQL workbench using the following command.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (columnone varchar, columntwo varchar, 
columnthree varchar,columnfour varchar,columnfive varchar,columnsix 
varchar,columnseven varchar,columneight varchar);
```

It is created successfully.

I verified the table is created from the following line. and saw the table is present and table_type is BASE TABLE

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public';
```

I was able to insert the data into the table.

```
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('123456', '123456', 
'123456','123456', '123456','123456','123456','123456');
```

Row insertion is done successfully

After that I performed the query

```
 Select * from test_table
```

and I'm able to see the results as well for this

But after 5 to 10 mins table is deleted.

I checked that table is not available in the DB by executing the following line

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public';
```

I googled it and was not able to find any. I'm new to redshift and SQL was there any mistake I did while creating the table. The tables that are created in this DB by some other people earlier are available still. I also checked with the people who created tables earlier are not able to figure out what is the issue

Comment: What message do you get when you run `Select * from test_table` after 5 minutes?

Comment: I'm seeing the following error:

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:

    select * from test_table

    [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "test_table" does not exist;
    1 statement failed.

    Execution time: 0.16s

Comment: make sure you "commit;" your changes

Comment: is there any option like commit, after creating the table. can you share some information about it? 
I checked with people who created tables earlier they never did something like commit.

Comment: depending on how you connected you may need to commit; on its own on a line - just submit it. wont do any harm

Comment: I connected it using SQL workbench by selecting the Amazon Redshift driver. I provided the JDBC URL, username, and password to connect. But there is no option to do commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Jon Scott comment, I tried using commit command and then I able to see the table after a long time as well. The table is not deleted now.

```
commit;
```

This is the command I executed after the creation of the table immediately.

Also, have gone through this we have to execute this commit after performing any operation on the table else the data will not change.

Also, I have seen another option after exploring the SQL workbench connect window. There is a checkbox for Autocommit. if we select the checkbox then we need not execute the commit command everytime